# Defining CSS sub-roots

Tags: css, css-variables

Suppose I have a `--primary-color` variable in my :root.

Suppose I have dozens of components that have a color attribute, and I want their color to be the same as the `--primary-color`. Normally I would have to define their color within the root, e.g.

```css
:root{
  --primary-color: red;
  --calendar-border-color: var(--primary-color);
}
```

This is fine for a small amount of simple components, but what if I have dozens and dozens of components, all of which have several attributes that rely on the :root variables? I don't want the root to be hundreds of lines long, and make it hard to navigate to the one component attribute I need to change.

What makes more sense to me, is to have a calendar.css file, and define a subroot/constructor/whatever where I just fetch the root variables, and then can define my own variables for that class, e.g.

```css
calendar.css

:sub-root{
  --calendar-border-color:    var(--primary-color);
  --calendar-highlight-color: var(--secondary-color);
  --calendar-important-color: var(--third-color);
  --calendar-default-color:   var(--default-color);

}

.calendar-border{
  color: var(--calendar-border-color);
  height: 20px;
 //etc...
```

And from there I can just change that one file where I know where everything is.

I imagine something like this exists, right?

edit:

Seems to work for the most part, but not all the way. Originally, I was calling .calendar in a class name on the main div for the component:

```css
.calendar {
  --calendar-background-color: red;
  background-color: var(--calendar-background-color)
}
```

So I moved it and renamed the div class name to 'calendar-main':

```css
.calendar{
  --calendar-background-color: red;
}

.calendar-main{
  background-color: var(--calendar-background-color)
}
```

and this seems to work for some attributes, but not others. any idea what's going on?

Comment: use the body selector as your sub-root, it will do the job

Comment: There's no such thing as "sub-roots", just elements, so pick an element that is the "root" for the variables you're defining, and define them there. They will be available to all elements lower in the cascade.

Comment: @TemaniAfif the body selector in the main.css? That would defeat what I'm trying to, wouldn't it?

Comment: @HereticMonkey I'm aware there isn't a such thing, but I figure that this looks like a relatively common issue that probably has been addressed before. I'm not sure what you mean by selecting a root element.

Comment: it won't, the :root is equivalent to the `html` element so the `body` is a perfect sub-root element

Comment: @TemaniAfif But the reason I'm avoiding putting everything in root is because I don't want everything in one file. I want to just define the basic variables that every component might or might not need, and then each component's own css file takes those main variables and does something with them

Comment: You probably want something like custom elements with Shadow DOM: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM

Comment: So, this calendar.css file is for a calendar component or something, right? Typically one has an element, say `<div class="calendar">` that wraps the contents of the component. Use `.calendar` as the selector instead of `:root`, so something like `.calendar { --calendar-border-color: #000; }` Any element that is a descendant of `.calendar` will be able to access those variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MDN's documentation on Using CSS custom properties:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties)

> Declaring a custom property is done using a custom property name that begins with a double hyphen (`--`), and a property value that can be any valid CSS value. Like any other property, this is written inside a ruleset, like so:
>
> ```
> element {
>   --main-bg-color: brown;
> }
> ```
>
> Note that the selector given to the ruleset defines the scope that the custom property can be used in.

Based on that, we can use any selector in place of `:root` or (in the example quoted) `element`, and the properties defined in the ruleset will be scoped to that selector.

Without knowing the HTML structure of your component, it's hard to say whether this will work with high confidence, but say your calendar component had a structure like this:

```html
<div class="calendar">
  <select class="month"><option>Select month</option></select>
  <select class="year"><option>Select year</option></select>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>S</th>
        <th>M</th>
        <th>T</th>
        <th>W</th>
        <th>T</th>
        <th>F</th>
        <th>S</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     ...days...
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

You could then structure your variables like so:

```css
.calendar {
  --calendar-border: #000;
  --calendar-weekday-font-weight: bold;
  --calendar-day-font-weight: normal;
  --calendar-day-today-font-weight: bold;
  --calendar-day-selected-font-weight: bold;
}

.calendar th {
  font-weight: var(--calendar-weekday-font-weight);
}
.calendar td {
  font-weight: var(--calendar-day-font-weight);
}
.calendar td.selected {
  font-weight: var(--calendar-day-selected-font-weight);
}
.calendar td.today {
  font-weight: var(--calendar-day-today-font-weight);
}
```

Comment: I addressed your reply in my edit (comments don't allow new lines)

Comment: This question was how do you create "sub-roots", and I think my post answers that, at least according to the specification. If there are issues with the behavior of the implementation of that in browsers, I would think that rises to the level of a new question, or else the answers become unwieldy.